# does a 7mm 2.5" inch SSHD fit a Mac mini 9.5mm HDD area without any additional work?

Tags: mac-mini, hdd

I have a Mac mini (Mac Mini 5,1 Mid 2011 , 2.3GHz intel Core i5, 4GB RAM) model that has a stock HDD (Toshiba MK5065GSX 500 GB SATA III 5400 RPM).

The HDD has a SMART issue and I have ordered Seagate's ST500LM000 (500 GB laptop thin SSHD).
The only thing I am worried now is that Toshiba HDD had 9.5mm size while the SSHD has 7mm thickness. Would new SSHD be compatible and inserted without any extra stuff,effort and adjustment OR should I stick to a 9.5mm drive only ?

Answer (score 1):

I think there ought to be enough play in the connectors that it will fit without further modification.

The only real issue with a mini is that the drives are fixed from underneath rather than from the top. This will move the connectors by 2.5 mm from where they initially were.

Judging from the [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Mac+mini+Model+A1283+Terabyte+Drive+Replacement/660) guide on adding a second drive, there would appear to be enough play in that connector strip that you will get away with that small move.

Compared to all the effort to get in there, though, if you find you don't have enough play in it, packing out the top by a couple of mm really shouldn't be much of a challenge. We're talking beermat depth, or a couple of pieces of folded card, not major engineering work.

Comment: So In short,if 7mm new Seagate SSHD has play due to additional space on top, I can put some stuff over there to adjust and can get away with that. No need to purchase additional 7mm to 9.5mm connector.. right ?

Comment: the only difference between the 2 drives, physically, is the height. If it were anything other than a mini, that would be zero issue, because the height from the base to the sockets would be identical - but a mini actually mounts the drive 'upwards' from the bottom of the device, so yes, it might need some simple packing just to make up that 2.5mm gap.